# Запретить создавать новый Toast, если он уже отображается на экране

Tags: android

Вопрос совсем простой. Как контролировать кол-во выводов Toast.makeText?

Вчера тестировал свое приложение на группе студентов. Один из них воспроизвел странный для меня баг. Он  нажал на кнопку много-много раз с его слов, после чего Toast.maketText в прямом смысле зациклился в стал выводить сообщение, даже после закрытия приложения. Как думаете, он просто забил очередь? И как можно обработать подобный случай?

Спасибо=)

Comment: это нативное поведение Toast, какой у вас вопрос? Слово контролировать здесь особо размывает суть

Comment: я бы хотел избежать потобного поведения? нельзя ли поставить флаг, запрещающий вывод сообщения, пока другое отображается?

Comment: это не баг а нормальное поведение скорее всего вам надо изменить логику. Советую после нажатия кнопки делать не доступной на Н-ое время пока тосты не покажетися и не исчезнет

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сделать заплатку:

```
toastLenght = 2000 (для Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) или 3500 (для Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

if(!isToast) {
    Toast.makeText(...);
    isToast = true;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isToast = false;
        }
    }, toastLenght);
}
```